# Cognos Report Rendering Issue: Gender Field Visibility Based on Customer ID Count

Tags: cognos

I have a Cognos report connected to an Oracle database, featuring 4 prompt pages :
[image]designed using a table structure with two columns: one for description and the other for Cognos value prompts .

On the first prompt page, users input customer IDs, and on the second page, there are fields displaying Average Salary, Average Age, Average Height, etc., including a Gender Field. My objective is to show the Gender field only if just one customer ID is entered on the first prompt page.

To achieve this, I created a separate query to return the count of customer IDs selected on the first prompt page. I then used the output of this query to create an expression for a variable. Expression is as follows:

```html
if ([Main_Case_List_Count].[CASE_COUNT] = 1) then (true) else (false)
```

The variable was successfully validated without errors. Subsequently, I implemented rendering using this variable, intending to display the Gender field conditionally.

However, when I run or validate the report, it throws an error :
**RSV-VAL-0034 Failed to validate the variable Boolean1. CRX-YXX-4010 A parsing error was found at or near the position 58 in the expression "if ([Main_Case_List_Count].[CASE_COUNT] = 1)    then (true)   else (false) "..**

. I'm seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Any insights into why the data item might not be recognized during runtime would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Report spec please.  If necessary for privacy, demonstrate the problem by developing a report using the GO Sales (query) package.

Comment: What Cognos product and version?  Looks like Cognos Analytics 11.something

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need another query to do this.  Create a string variable with the following expression, where PL is your prompt name.

```
 if (ParamDisplayValue('PL') is missing)  then  ('NoDisplay') else
('Display')
```

The string variable will need the two values added, NoDisplay and Display.

Once that is in place you can try this to a render variable on the singleton or List column depending on what you are using.

Comment: Another Query is needed because Data coming from first Prompt can not be used as is. That list of customer IDs has to go through some validations and the at the end of validations, we may or may not get any customer id. If the resultant customer id list has just one value then Prompt2 will be shown. This is the behavior.